# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: albums.path (code 1299)

Tags: android, sqlite

An exception happened in my app when I add a new item into my database.

```
Error inserting time=2016年05月14日 23:42:03 content=zxdc
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: albums.path (code 1299)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at com.driver.shinekaye.olddriver.AddContent.addDB(AddContent.java:53)
        at com.driver.shinekaye.olddriver.AddContent.onClick(AddContent.java:70)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cursor.getPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_secretalbum_item, null);
        TextView contentTv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        TextView timeTv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_time);
        ImageView imgIv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_img);
        ImageView videoIv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_video);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
        String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));
        contentTv.setText(content);
        timeTv.setText(time);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

The table:

```
public class SecretAlbumDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "albums";
    public static final String CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String PATH = "path";
    public static final String VIDEO = "video";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String TIME = "time";

    public SecretAlbumDB(Context context) {
        super(context, "albums", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + CONTENT
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + PATH
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + VIDEO
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + TIME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

The query

```
 public void selectDB() {
    Cursor cursor = dbReader.query(SecretAlbumDB.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, cursor);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The insert:

```
private void addDB() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SecretAlbumDB.CONTENT, editText.getText().toString());
    cv.put(SecretAlbumDB.TIME, getTime());
    dbWriter.insert(SecretAlbumDB.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the following NOT NULL values in your database definition:

```
CONTENT
PATH
VIDEO
TIME
```

But in your addDB you only put CONTENT and TIME in ContentValues so it definitely looking for PATH and VIDEO too. If they aren't present, it will give the error. There are two solution:

Solution 1:

remove NOT NULL constraint from VIDEO and PATH:

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + CONTENT
            + " TEXT NOT NULL," + PATH
            + " TEXT," + VIDEO
            + " TEXT," + TIME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
```

Solution 2:

add VIDEO and PATH to ContentValues:

```
private void addDB() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SecretAlbumDB.CONTENT, editText.getText().toString());
    cv.put(SecretAlbumDB.TIME, getTime());
    cv.put(SecretAlbumDB.VIDEO, getVideo());
    cv.put(SecretAlbumDB.Path, getPath());

    dbWriter.insert(SecretAlbumDB.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: I just started learning the sqlite, so I make such mistakes, thanks! Problems solved!

Comment: @Pooya Question won't be closed after accepting the answer though ! Not to worry.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna well I meant it won't appear on the first page list. I actually encountered many questions not marked as answered but you find in comments that the answer is OK and you should go through a lot of trouble reading questions and answers. This help other SO users to donate their time on unanswered questions

Comment: @Pooya Yah you are right.. 1 for your thought ! although its 16 min. late one than mine..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna +1 for you, although it seemed to me it needs more elaboration for the user

Answer (score 3):

For sure you have declared your all fields (columns) as `NOT NULL` and you've not put the value to those fields while inserting `cv`. Either make those columns `null` acceptable or put all the values to `cv` for every Columns that are `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If its information is from a remote source check that the result has no null values. I got a similar issue from an API result that was missing data yet I was trying to insert it directly into the database